# Commerce Order Model in Gateway Event Plugin Hook

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, php

I am trying to add some logic that can stop an order transaction from happening depending on values stored in the **Order Model**. Due to how my client wants the purchase page setup, I need to be able to do last-minute validating through the `commerce/payments/pay` action, which I can intervene before it happens using the `onBeforeGatewayRequestSend` event.

Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. The issue I am having is accessing the **Order Model**, It looks like it isn't available in the `$event` parameter - which is why the below doesn't work.

```
craft()->on('commerce_payments.onBeforeGatewayRequestSend', function($event) {

    // This doesn't work. No 'order' param available.
    $order = $event->params['order']; 

    /* logic using $order, 
    -- set $is_valid (boolean) */;

    if(!$is_valid) {

       $transaction = $event->params['transaction'];
       $transaction->message = "This order is not yet complete.";
       $event->performAction = false;
       return $event;

    }

});
```

Is it at all possible to get the order model inside of this hook? Or is this just not the right place to be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to the order from the transaction like this:

```
craft()->on('commerce_payments.onBeforeGatewayRequestSend', function($event) {

    $transaction = $event->params['transaction']; 
    $order = $transaction->order;

}
```

Comment: Ha - even easier.  Would be great if the transaction model was documented (and we could search the Commerce docs)!

Comment: @JeremyDaalder just added https://craftcommerce.com/docs/transaction-model

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is available for each event in the docs here:

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_payments.onbeforegatewayrequestsend

...and indeed order is not one of the parameters.  (I would say it should be really, and you might want to request @lukeholder add this!)

However it's very simple to get the current cart (it's a cart at this point, technically, but that's just an `OrderModel` that is not set as completed yet). Use this code:

```
$cart = craft()->commerce_cart->getCart();
```

One other note - you don't need to `return $event;` as the event is passed in by reference anyway (hence you can set `$event->performAction = false;` and that sets it on the original event passed in by reference, not a local copy of the event).

Comment: I feel sad that I never knew you could grab the cart like that, all this time! That's going to be helpful in a lot of other ways. Thanks for that and the return tip!

Comment: don't use `getCart()`, get the transaction's order as per my answer below.

Comment: Don't listen to that Luke guy, what does he know?! ;)